# Remove padding/magrin left and right in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to Vuetify. Here i confuse how to remove left and right margin/padding.

Here what I've done:

```
<template>
  <v-app light>
    <v-toolbar fixed app :clipped-left="clipped" color="deep-orange accent-3">
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>

      <v-toolbar-title v-text="title"></v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-content>
      <v-container pa-0 ma-0>
        <nuxt/>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>

    <v-footer :fixed="fixed" app></v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQzpC.png)

But as you can see, the grey box is still affected by margin/padding. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see what your `<nuxt/>` code is which may also have padding and margins, but `<v-container>` has a `max-width` property which may be the issue you're coming across. Try add a ` style="max-width:100%;"` into your `<v-container>` and see if that helps.

Comment: `<v-container fluid pa-0>` might work.